# Possible to foreach loop to produce and store R2 data as a new column while removing current variable

Tags: data-science, stata

I am trying to design a foreach loop that will regress two variables time (x) and y and but by removing the current variable for each year to check how removing the current time (x variable) affects the Rsq for the regression. Then I want to store the R2 for each regression in a new column so I can find which regression has the highest R2 when that given time is removed. Here is what I have below:

```
foreach x in varlist year {
quietly regress y year
gen Rsq = e(r2)
}
```

I am not used to Stata syntax and I am finding it very difficult, thank you!!

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "removing the current variable for each year to check how removing the current time...". Do you want to stratify your sample along year and run on each subsample? More generally, I suggest you look at the Stata help file for `foreach` as your current syntax mixes `in` and the `varlist` keyword; though this isn't invalid, it is likely not what you intend.

Comment: Yes sorry, I mean to put: ` foreach x of varlist year { ` I am trying to see in which time period there is a trend break and I want to find this trend break by going through each year one by one and removing the current year to see if the Rsq is higher as a result of removing it.

Comment: I want to do something similar to this: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1319464-regression-with-and-without-one-observation but in a foreach loop to gather Rsq that are then added to a new column in my dataset. To specify another way, for year 1 I want to calculate the Rsq for a regression of year vs independentvar (but excluding year1) and then for year2 I want to calculate the Rsq for a regression of year vs independentvar (but excluding year2). I am not sure if it would be better to replace the independentvar for 0 for this single regression.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your clarifications, I think this will work for your purpose. Note that `foreach x of varlist year {` will not access the distinct values of `year`. This is asking Stata to loop over the `varlist` containing only `year`; what you want is the `levelsof` command.

```
// Create sample data 
clear all 
set seed 2021
set obs 5
gen year = _n + 2000 
expand 200
gen y = rnormal() + 3*year

// for loop 
levelsof year, local(years)
foreach yr of local years {
    disp "The year omitted is `yr'"
    reg y year if year != `yr'
    gen Rsq_omit_`yr' =  e(r2) 
}
```

If you want the values to be contained in one variable where the R-squared is aligned with the omitted year, you can do this:

```
gen Rsq = .
levelsof year, local(years)
foreach yr of local years {
    disp "The year omitted is `yr'"
    reg y year if year != `yr'
    replace Rsq = e(r2) if year == `yr'
}

. tabdisp year, c(Rsq)

----------------------
     year |        Rsq
----------+-----------
     2001 |  .91367307
     2002 |  .95367692
     2003 |  .95636972
     2004 |  .95240147
     2005 |  .92448613
----------------------
```

Comment: To show the results compactly, try `tabdisp year, c(Rsq)`

Comment: Nice, that's a neat trick. Thanks @NickCox